# Typescript: Model driven and Type safe Specification with autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, dsl

I found this $SPEC tagged template literal prototype

```js
function $SPEC<Keys extends string[]>([result, ...parts]: TemplateStringsArray, ...keys: Keys) {
  
  return (params: { [K in Keys[number]]: string }) => 
  
    keys.reduce((acc, key: keyof typeof params, i) => acc + params[key] + parts[i], result)
        
}
```

It has possibility to "interpolate" a Specification in markdown - with ${`Data`}

```js
const TestScenario = $SPEC `

# Feature XY 
>> As ${`role`} I want XY because of benefit ...

Scenario:
  - given ${`Entity 1`} ...
  - when ...
  - then ...
    
`
```

And so far this "interpolation driven" Specification is "somehow" Type safe and with autocomplete - but for `Data` only.

```js
const TestCase  = TestScenario({ // Test `Data`

        'role': `Editor`,
        'Entity 1': `example 1`

})
```

[current type safety and autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72aj8.png)

[Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBjknN)

HOW can I go further with Type safe and autocomplete - for $SPEC - to be even MORE "MODEL DRIVEN" ?

GOALS:

- for a collective of Analysts and Testers (with minimal coding skills)
- I am looking for MINIMAListics TYPESCRIPT SYNTAX and implementation (see prototype above)
- wanted syntax for intersectional $SPECification should be: (Domain) MODEL DRIVEN & TYPE SAFE (against model/s) & WITH intellisense / AUTOCOMPLETE (productivity)

TERMINOLOGY:

- it appears that an Analyst and Tester Specifications have intersections at least in:

  - Domain terms - elements from the Model/s
  - and Scenarios - TestCase is usually based on a scenario from UseCase / UserStory + adds TestData via domain EXAMPLES (according to Model)

CONCEPT + WORKFLOW SAMPLE:

```js
// sorry - this is only pseudocode (I'm just starting with Typescript and I don't know the relevant syntax, so I'm introducing "alternative syntax" where possible :)


// 1. DomainModels.ts - via Typescript Interfaces - from @Analyst

type Attribute = {}; type Action = {}; // structure is not important for now :)

interface role {}
interface Repository1 {}
interface Entity2 {
  'Simple att3': Attribute
  'Complex att4': {
    'Att5': Attribute
    // ...
  }
  'Action N': Action
}


// 2. Specifications.md.ts - via markdown, wrapped in MINIMAList Typescript - from @Anlayst and @Tester also

// declare function $SPEC (...) ...
const UseCase =  $SPEC
const TestScenario = $SPEC

// ... probably irrelevant syntax 
const UC1 = UseCase<{role, Repository1, Entity2}> 
`
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
>> vvvvvvvv ${`role`} vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
- vv ${`Repository1`} vvvvvvvvvv ${`Entity2.Simple att3`} vvv
- vvvvvvv ${`Entity2.Action N`} vvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
`

// ... other syntax alternatives ?
// const TS2 = TestScenario<[role, Repository1, Entity2]> `...`
// const Scenario3 = $SPEC<role | Repository1 | Entity2> `...`

// ALL "syntaxes / alternatives" only TRY to "DELIVER" MODELS TO $SPEC

// ... or this alternative would be nice - has "shortcuts" for "models" :)
const Scenario4 = $SPEC( (r: role, rep: Repository1, e: Partial<Entity2>) => `
>> vvvvvvvv ${r} vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
- vv ${rep} vvvvvvvvvv ${e['Simple att3']} vvv
- vvvvvvv ${e['Action N']} vvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
` )


// 3. Examples.ts - via Typescript call of $SPEC() "aliases" - from @Tester

const TC4_1 = Scenario4( // again, exact structure of some parameters is not important for now :)
  {}, // r:   role 
  {}, // rep: repository
  {   // e:   Partial<Entity2>
    'Simple att3': 'example 1',
    'Action N': () => {}
  }
)
```

So please, can you advise YOUR MINIMAList Typescript SYNTAX (and implementation if possible) FOR the GIVEN CONCEPT ???

Or do you know some framework / library / tool like this or close to concept of "Model Driven Type safe Specification" ???
(I know about Cucumber and Gauge, they are close, but not exactly what I'm looking for)

I will be grateful for any suggestions or opinions - they are very welcome.

THANK YOU (if you read to this point - I couldn't cut it :)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDPkRN)?  If so, I could write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz. You're close. Sorry, my mistake in an inaccurate question. I tried to clarify it and also stated the Goals, Terminology and Workflow with a Sample. Is it clearer now please? Regards.

Comment: Your Scenario4 seems like a no-op to me, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7KDW). If that works, great.  Your other scenarios seem to need name mapping and ordering information at runtime that you're not passing in, so the only reasonable solution I can think of looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJPEW).  Do either of these work for you?

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately, neither works for me. The first one is no-op, as you say. And the second creates a model **AT** the Outline/$SPEC point, but the model is known **BEFORE** that point. Too bad for me, it evolved so promisingly :(

Comment: The first one is a no-op because that’s what you are asking for; if it doesn’t work, can you demonstrate how?  For the second one, can you articulate why that matters and demonstrate the failure?  Preferably with a code example that shows explicitly how each suggested solution does not work.  I’m willing to work on this more but I need more than a verbal description of the problem.

Comment: @jcalz I uderstand, my sample in question is confusing - so [here](https://tsplay.dev/NnQKew) is more clearer illustration with code :) If now it is more clearer, I will update the question. Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the scope keeps widening based on my responses, as opposed to being clarified, so I'm worried about continuing to engage. The original `Scenario4` wasn't something you actually wanted at all, I guess, so maybe we should stop talking about it.  The new `Scenario4` is not possible as written, since there's no way for the compiler to know that the callback you pass to `$SPEC` doesn't actually care about most of its arguments, nor would the compiler be able to match an object key like `e` with the name of the callback's parameter, an unexposed implementation detail.

Comment: Okay, [this](//tsplay.dev/WvVKkW) is my final offer.  It requires currying to work around [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), but it is as good as you could possibly get with TypeScript.  You need to pass in a list of model types for the compiler, and you need to pass in a list of "top-level" object names for the implementation, and then you get exactly the autocomplete you're looking for, I believe.  If you don't want this as your answer, maybe you should just leave this on read, since I think my heart would break at this point if it's still not what you want .

Comment: @jcalz first of all you have my great respect and gratitude - you are kind, patient and professional. 
Sorry, Typescript is not my programming language, English is not my native language and I know - I have trouble formulating concisely and clearly what I would need in my native language as well. 
I don't want to break your heart, so I studied these and your other answers. 
And yes, they are what I needed [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nabr9m). 
Please, I would be encouraged if you check, correct it and post an answer to others as well - I accept any your answer immediately :) Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @jcalz there is this solution:

```js
type _K2O<K extends string, V = unknown> =
K extends `${infer F}.${infer R}` ? { [P in F]: _K2O<R, V> } : { [P in K]: V }

type DeepMerge<T> = { [K in keyof T]: DeepMerge<T[K]> } extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type KeyToObject<K extends string, V = unknown> = (K extends unknown ? (x: _K2O<K, V>) => void : never) extends
  (x: infer O) => void ? DeepMerge<O> : never;

type DotPrefix<T extends string> = T extends "" ? "" : `.${T}`

type DotNestedKeys<T> = (T extends object ?
  { [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]: `${K}${DotPrefix<DotNestedKeys<T[K]>>}` }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]
  : "") extends infer D ? Extract<D, string> : ''; // here I intuitively changed : never to : '', because of problem with next split()

function $SPEC<M>() {
  return <Keys extends DotNestedKeys<M>[]>([result, ...parts]: TemplateStringsArray, ...keys: Keys) => {
    return (params: KeyToObject<Keys[number], string>): string =>
      keys.reduce((acc, key, i) => acc + (key.split(".").reduce<any>((o, k) => o[k], params)) + parts[i], result)
  }
}
```

```js
// 1. DomainModels.ts

interface Entity2 {
  'Simple att3': string
  'Complex att4': {
    'Att5': string
    // ...
  }
  'Action N': string
}

// 2. Specifications.md.ts

const TestScenario = $SPEC;

const TS1 = TestScenario<{role: string, entity2: Entity2}>()
`
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
>> vvvvvvvv ${`role`} vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
- vvvvvvvvvvvv ${`entity2.Simple att3`} vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
- vvvvvvv ${`entity2.Action N`} vvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
`

// 3. Examples.ts

TS1({ // TestCase aka Example = [TestScenario, TestData]
  role: `Editor`,
  entity2: {
    'Simple att3': `example 1`,
    'Action N': `exmple 2`
  }
})
```

[$SPEC resp. TestScenario resp. TS1 now also has autocomplete and is interface aka model driven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSsi6.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).